# Why can't I read the property value in event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to access the value of the material ui text input i am using when i call the function but i also need to pass through other parameters,

this is the code that calls the function in its parent class.

```
<Input
    value={this.props.appState.application.Person[0].Forename}
    className={classes.input}
    onChange={this.testHandleChange(0, 'Person')}
    name="Forename"
    inputProps={{
      'aria-label': 'Description',
    }}
/>
```

And this is the function it calls in the parent

```
testHandleChange = event => (userIndex, object) => {
    console.log(`userIndex: ${userIndex}`);
    console.log(`object: ${object}`);
    console.log(`value: ${event.target.value}`);
};
```

it keeps saying unexpected use of the global 'event'. on the input but not on the function how do i fix this?

edit: so i have changed something slightly and got a bit of a better error i think ill change the code above.

this now gives me the error

> cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing:

```
event => (userIndex, object) =>
```

But this means you are returning a function that takes params of (userIndex, object) and pass that to onChange.
But it must be:

```
(userIndex, object) => event =>
```

Here you are returning a function that takes an event as a param. That is what onChange expects.

Comment: Please give some more context to your answer so people can understand whats going on better

Comment: Perfect works like a charm so you put things your not passing through last if they are global variables?

Comment: There is more than enough context there to know what ive done wrong

Comment: @andrewwilson it is simply the order.  You want to *return* a function that takes an `event`, not the other way round.

Comment: @DavinTryon How would i add the global name to the same function sorry to ask a question on a question like this but its the same thing i tried just adding it like this `(userIndex, object) => name => event =>` but that didnt work the function didnt even call

Comment: @andrewwilson do you mean the message you are getting about `event` being a reserved word?  Just change the name of the `event` parameter to `e`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Better way to solve this would be to catch the event with anonymous functions and pass it on as an arg :

```
onChange={(event) => { this.testHandleChange(event, 0, 'Person'); }}
```

and then in your handler :

```
testHandleChange = (event, userIndex, object) => { ... }
```